# Почему в Chrome скрипт отрабатывается позже чем в firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Всем привет, имеется вот такой вот код

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.animated = function(inEffect, outEffect) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0").addClass("animated").waypoint(function(dir) {
                        console.log(dir)
                        if (dir === "down") {
                                $(this).removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        } else {
                                $(this).removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        };
                }, {
                        offset: "100%"
                }).waypoint(function(dir) {
                    console.log(dir)
                        if (dir === "down") {
                                $(this).removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        } else {
                                $(this).removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        };
                }, {
                        offset: -$(window).height()
                });
        };
})(jQuery);
```

При загрузке страницы консоль в хроме выдает предупреждение:

Handling of 'mousewheel' input event was delayed for 423 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responive.

Как мне избавится от задержки?